# How to solve the sequence limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence limit is:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\right]$$

I rationalized and got:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}\right]$$
After this procedure I got stuck

Comment: I would guess you can either squeze it or do conjugate rule.

Comment: But the denomiator still constains square roots. What have you done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. It should be
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}}+1}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n}}}.$$
Can you take it from here?